# Ruby on Rails - Parse Ruby Client Gem - How to process failed user authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

I'm using the [parse-ruby-client](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client) gem to create a web version of my app that works with my Parse database. I want users to login, but currently if the authentication fails, I get an error:

```
Parse::ParseProtocolError in UsersController#authenticate
101: invalid login parameters
```

This is what I tried, but the if statement doesn't work this way:

```
user = Parse::User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])

if user
  # Save new session, redirect, etc.
else
  # redirect back to login form and try again
end
```

If the login parameters don't match an existing user, the app crashes. How do I validate what the authenticate method returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the info given it appears the parse client you are using throws an error when it fails to authenticate. So the solution is to catch the error.

```
def authenticate
  user = Parse::User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
  # Save new session, redirect, etc.
rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError
  # redirect back to login form and try again
end
```